# How to prove that there is no algorithm to create context free grammar by the description

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar, formal-proofs

I have following information:

Alphabet $\Sigma$ , where $\Sigma \cap \{T,U\} = \emptyset $
and language $L = L(G) $ over $\Sigma$ generated by context free grammar $G$.

Then I consider another language $L'$ that is defined as follows

$L' = \{w.a | w \in \Sigma^* \land (w \in L \iff a = T) \land (w \notin L \iff a = U)  \}$

Based on this information I have to conclude whether there is an algorithm that can create context free grammar $G'$ so that $L(G') = L'$. If there is no such algorithm I should prove it.

I concluded that there is not such algorithm, since I know that context free languages are not closed against complement, therefore the complement of language can be even context-sensitive language.

If I am right, how do I now write down a proof of it? And I am not right, where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Focusing on whether there is an _algorithm_ in particular seems to be a slightly wrong approach. Instead the core question here is whether $L'$ is necessarily context-free at all. And you seem to be on the right path for proving it's not. What you need to argue now is that if $L'$ is context-free, then $\Sigma^*\setminus L$ would also be.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I got to the point where I realized that $L' = L . {T} \cup \overline{\rm L} . {U} $ Based on that I proceeded to realize that union of context-free with complement of non-context free language could result in language that can not be generated by context-free grammar. Is this valid approach, or I'm of the right path now?

Comment: x @FanaticD: No you're going in the wrong direction -- you would need to _assume_ that $L'$ is _already_ context-free and then prove that if this is the case then $\bar L$ would be that too. A first step would be to intersect with a regular language to get that $\bar L\mathtt U$ would be context-free, but you may need to describe some ad-hoc rewriting of grammars to argue that if $\bar L\mathtt U$ is context-free, then $\bar L$ is context-free too.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Alright, but when I am supposed to write an algorithm so that $L(G') = L'$ where $G'$ is context-free grammar, wouldn't that mean that $L'$ must be generated by context-free grammar, therefore at worst it's context-free or regular? Maybe I could assume that $L'$ is context-free? And to backup my comment theory - given language $L$ of type-2 (Chomsky hierarchy) and a language $L'$ of type-1 or type-0 ("more general" I would say) what will be the type of $L'' = L \cup L'$?

Comment: Your task is to describe such an algorithm OR prove that it cannot exist. You have already decided that it cannot exiat, so now your task is to prove _that_.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. Pick a specific context free language L whose complement isn't context free. For example, L could be {x : x≠ww for any w}.

We can prove by contradiction that L' is not context free. If L' is context free, then its intersection with any regular language is also context free. So L' intersected with Σ*U is context free. But intersecting with this language produces, basically, the set of all strings in the complement of L. But we already know (or we can prove) that the complement of L is not context free. This completes the proof.